# Multiple onclicks on the same div

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am trying to add a second `onclick` function to my element but so far without success, tried with different separators, same quotations and such but it does not work yet.

This is the code :

```
<a title="course"  onclick="if(document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display='none'};" onclick="if(document.getElementById('nav-res') .style.display=='block') {document.getElementById('nav-res') .style.display='none'};">Course</a>
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong ? Much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add multiple `onclick` statements.
You need to add a semicolon ( ; ) between the commands.

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('this is command 1'); alert('this is command 2');">click me</a>
//---------------------------------------------^---------------------------^
```

However, I would not do it the way you are doing it.
I would make a separate function that does whatever you are trying to do.
It's not good practice to put everything in the html (inline).

I would do it like this:

```
<a id="" onclick="clickme()">
<script>
    function clickme() {
        // action 1
        if( document.getElementById('spoiler').style.display=='none' ){
            document.getElementById('spoiler').style.display='';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('spoiler').style.display='none';
        };
        // action 2
        if( document.getElementById('nav-res').style.display=='block' ){
            document.getElementById('nav-res') .style.display='none';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: so i can't use 2 onclicks on the same element ?

Comment: no you can't. you can use only one html attribute of each type on each tag.

Comment: @AryehArmon - good answer! Please take a look at the edits I have made. I hope you agree with me that they are an improvement. Also take care to verify your code is working - you had some issues with quotes in your first line of code

Comment: thank you, i just added a p tag to course and added the 2nd onclick in the p tag , now it works fine but i will use that code above for something later on, so thank you very much for this :)

Answer (score 3):

I encourage you to try using event listeners:

```
<a href='#' id='mytag'>
```

and then:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('mytag').addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert(1)
  }, false);

  document.getElementById('mytag').addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert(2)
  }, false);
</script>
```

or with jquery:

```
<script>
  $('#mytag').click(function(){ alert(1) })
  $('#mytag').click(function(){ alert(2) })
</script>
```